# Java: leaving the recursive method call and the loop

Tags: java, spring-boot, recursion

I have a service to get the validator content as a string after passing the validator id (name). The validator's XSL files are placed in the src/main/resources. I am scanning the validator directory in the src/main/resources/de/validators to check if the file is a vailable. I am converting its input to a string and returning it as result fot the service.

In the findFile() method I want to leave the recursive call and the loop after finding the match. Is that possiable in my case?
Currently I am assigning the match to the fileName class attribute which works for me. A better approach would be to break the recursive call if it is possiable in my case.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import de.validate.exception.ApiRequestException;

@RequestMapping("/api/v1/validators")
@RestController
public class ValidateService {

    private String fileName = "";

    static private Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ValidateService.class.getName());
    final static private String VALIDATOR_CONFIGURATION_DIRECTORY = "de" +  File.separator + "validator" + File.separator;
    final static private String VALIDATOR_TYPE = ".xsl";
    final static private String VALIDATOR = "validator";

    @GetMapping(path = "{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public String getValidator(@PathVariable String id) throws Exception {

        URL resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(VALIDATOR_CONFIGURATION_DIRECTORY);
        File validatorDirectory = Paths.get(resource.toURI()).toFile();
        String foundId = this.findFile(id + VALIDATOR_TYPE, validatorDirectory);

        String fileNameTemp = VALIDATOR_CONFIGURATION_DIRECTORY + foundId;

        InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileNameTemp);
        if (inputStream == null) {
            throw new ApiRequestException("Validator id is not availabe!");
        }

        String result = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)).lines()
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        LOGGER.info("---> result: " + result);
        return result;

    }


    public String findFile(String name, File file) {

        File[] list = file.listFiles();
        if (list != null)
            for (File fileTemp : list) {
                if (fileTemp.isDirectory()) {
                    this.findFile(name, fileTemp);
                } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(fileTemp.getName())) {
                    //Is it possible to break the loop here and the recursive invoke?
                    if (fileTemp.getParentFile().getName().equals(VALIDATOR)) {
                        fileName = name;
                    } else {
                        fileName = fileTemp.getParentFile().getName() + File.separator + name;
                    }
                }
            }

        return fileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "break; the recursive call in the loop" mean?

Comment: leaving the loop and the recursive method "findFile".

Comment: you can just do a `return` there . . . BTW the return value of the recursive call is not being used at all, probably not intended

Comment: @user16320675 return is not worked if the recursive method findFile has been called several time before finding the matched file.

Comment: For example the return will not work if the matched file was found in a subdirectory in the validators directory . It would work if the matched file is placed inside the validators directory directly.